# Using Python + Selenium to select a tag within divs of a class within a div?

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors

Alright so, what I'm trying to do is searching for the first a tags within the divs of a specific class, in a div with a specific ID. Using Python + Selenium offcourse.

Right now I have as my code

```
newest_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.elements > a")
```

What this is doing is searching for all divs in a page with class "elements", and taking the very top most link from those divs. But I do not want to search all of the divs on the entire page with the class "elements". I only want to search the "elements" divs that are in another larger div with an specific id called "list-all".

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance for your help guys

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description instead of

```py
newest_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.elements > a")
```

You should use

```py
newest_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#list-all div.elements > a")
```

You may possibly add waits / delays here.